# Sharepoint 2010 publishing page personalization - Error "Add and Customize Pages permissions"

Tags: web-part, error, permissions

I'm trying to enable users to customize the home page of my publishing site. For testing purposes, i have changed the "Read" role to allow "Add/Remove Personal Web Parts" and "Update Personal Web Parts" permissions. By doing this, the user gets a "Personalize this Page" option in the drop down when they click on the "Welcome" user section. Once in the personalization mode, they can completely interact with any existing web parts on the page. But if they try to add a new web part, this error pops up: "A Web Part or Web Form Control on this Page cannot be displayed or imported. You don't have Add and Customize Pages permissions required to perform this action". I have also tried giving the "visitors" group, contribute permission on the Pages library, but still get the same error. Does anyone have any idea how I can accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please verify that you have checked permission for "Add and Customize pages" from SitePermission.

If that solves your issues, description lies [here](http://manish-sharepoint.blogspot.com/2010/04/contributor-getting-error-while-adding.html)